# Why do we need a move constructor for vector of unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

It seems that VC11 Update 2, requires a Move Constructor when pushing `unique_ptr`'s in an std::vector. Is this a documented behavior or a known Bug?

```
#include < iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
struct TEST
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> m_l;
    TEST(
        std::unique_ptr<int>&& l)
    {
        m_l = std::move(l);
    };
    //Move Contructor for Test
    TEST(TEST&& o)
    {
        m_l = std::move(o.m_l);
    }
};
void Bar()
{
    std::vector<TEST> vec;
    std::unique_ptr<int> a(new int);
    //Compiles fine without a Move Constructor
    TEST(std::move(a));
    //Requires a Move Contructor to compile
    vec.push_back(
        TEST(std::move(a)));
}
int main()
{       
    Bar();
    return 0;
}
```

**Note**

I tried the above code sans the Move Constructor on [IDEONE C++11](http://ideone.com/QrTryx) and it compiles fine.

Comment: This code does have a move constructor for TEST. Are you asking why you need to write it? i.e. IDEONE compiles it fine without the move constructor?

Comment: @doctorlove: Sorry if my question is confusing. IDEONE compiles fine without a Move Constructor where as VC11 requires one.

Comment: Try to use `emplace_back` as a workaround.

Comment: @user1095108 in VC11 isn't `emplace_back` the same as `push_back`?

Comment: @Simple No `emplace_back` will use the arguments you provide to initialize an instance at the back of the vector, whereas `push_back` can move an instance to the back, but this is not the same.

Comment: @user1095108 i'm aware of that, but VC10 treated `emplace_back` and `push_back` as the same thing AFAIK.

Comment: @Simple I don't know about that, could be, `VC` is strange.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't have to write the move constructor yourself; it should be automatically generated by the compiler in this case. However, VC11 doesn't implement this functionality and IIRC isn't going to be added until VS2013.

Note that VC11 is complaining because the presence of a `std::unique_ptr` data member causes your copy constructor to be deleted. §12.8p11 describes this process of deleting a class's copy constructor:

> An implicitly-declared copy/move constructor is an inline public
>   member of its class. **A defaulted copy/move constructor for a class X
>   is defined as deleted (8.4.3) if X has**:
>
> [...]
>
> — **a non-static data member of
>   class type M** (or array thereof) that **cannot be copied**/moved **because
>   overload resolution (13.3), as applied to M’s corresponding
>   constructor, results in** an ambiguity or **a function that is deleted** or
>   inaccessible from the defaulted constructor,
>
> [...]

Comment: Will VS2013 have implicitly defined move-constructors?

Comment: `Note that VC11 is complaining because the presence of a std::unique_ptr data member causes your copy constructor to be deleted.` ... Can you please explain this statement?

Comment: @Abhijit `std::unique_ptr` has no copy constructor, therefore a class that has one as a data member can't be copied and so its copy constructor is deleted. `std::unique_ptr` *can* be moved but VS doesn't automatically provide move constructors so the deleted copy constructor is always being selected and that's causing the compilation error.

Comment: @Simple: Makes sense, and a new thing I learned. But, is this documented per standards or assumed?

Comment: @Abhijit is which part documented? Copy constructors being deleted in this way is in the standard.